# Android Push Notification Using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing an android app using html5,css3 and javascript which can be used offline also.It has some data which i have stored in local storage.These data need to be sent as push notification.I am very new to android app.Can anybody please help me? Thanx in advance

Comment: but dude, you need to at least tell us how you are building your project! Are you using cordova, have you checked the API of the framework you are using and checked if it's possible what you are asking?

Comment: I am developing it using html5 and javascript and after that i am converting it into .apk using Phonegap. Now i need to push the notification on the android app.

Comment: You'll have to use a notification plugin. I don't know which one to recommend since I haven't needed to use one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out this plugin, which is for Cordova, but it was linked from the Phonegap page

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.dialogs

And here I was looking when I found it

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs